# Is there a way to easily parse the year from the [site.time] property in Jekyll?

Tags: ruby, liquid, jekyll

Is there a way to just pull the year (or any other element... month, day, etc) from the `site.time` property that is available to your template file in [Jekyll](http://wiki.github.com/mojombo/jekyll)?

Right now it returns, for example: `Sat Dec 19 14:07:03 -0700 2009`

Any help is appreciated. **Thanks!**

Comment: Should i dump the Ruby tag now that we have the new tag? Jekyll is a Ruby project (i think), but I'm not sure how related my question is to Ruby iteslf. I'm not trying to get a boatload of views or anything.

Comment: @Adam: Jekyll is definitely Ruby, and it doesn't hurt to keep the tag. I also added a Liquid tag, since your question relates to the templating engine Jekyll uses, Liquid.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `site.time` item is available for templating using Liquid, so I think that you want something like this:

```
<h2>last modified: {{site.time | date: "%Y%m%d"}}</h2>
```

See here for more on Liquid: [Liquid for Designers](https://github.com/Shopify/liquid/wiki/Liquid-for-Designers).